# Getting Native Handle from Within a Thread?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, c++11

I am using VS2012 and I want to set thread priority from within a running thread. The goal is to initialize all threads with the highest priority state. To do this I want to get a `HANDLE` to the thread.

I am having some trouble accessing the pointer that corresponds to the `thread` object.

Is this possible?

From the calling main thread, the pointer is valid and from the C++11 thread it is set to `CCCCCCCC`. Predictably dereferencing some nonsense memory location causes a crash.

The code below is a simplified version showing the problem.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
using namespace std;
class threadContainer
    {
    thread* mT;
    condition_variable* con;
    void lockMe()
        {
        mutex m;
        unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
        con->wait(lock);//waits for host thread
        cout << mT << endl;//CCCCCCCC
        auto h = mT->native_handle();//causes a crash
        con->wait(lock);//locks forever
        }
    public:
        void run()
            {
            con = new condition_variable();
            mT = new thread(&threadContainer::lockMe,*this);
            cout << mT << endl; //00326420
            con->notify_one();// Without this line everything locks as expected
            mT->join();
            }
    };
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
    threadContainer mContainer;
    mContainer.run();
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: A Google search for `condition_variable` suggests that `con->wait(lock)` may be subject to spurious wakeups.  What happens if you don't try to wake up the new thread?

Comment: @HarryJohnston it locks as expected. I tried to add a large delay between `cout << mT << endl; //00326420` and `con->notify_one();` so I don't think this is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

class threadContainer {
   std::thread* mT;
  std::mutex m;
  void lockMe() {
    // wait for mT to be assigned:
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
    }
    std::cout << "lockMe():" << mT << "\n";
    auto h = mT->native_handle();//causes a crash
    std::cout << "Done lockMe!\n";
  }
  public:
    void run() {
      // release lock only after mT assigned:
      {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
        mT = new std::thread( [&](){ this->lockMe(); } );
      }
      std::cout << "run():" << mT << "\n"; //00326420
      mT->join();
    }
};

int main() {
  threadContainer mContainer;
  mContainer.run();
  return 0;
}
```

Try that.

Comment: Wow. This seems to work, could you explain what the `{}` are doing? I can't figure out what unlocks the c++11 thread.

Comment: They define scopes.  So each `unique_lock` goes out of scope at the matching `}`.  As the thread is started after the mutex is locked, it cannot lock that mutex until the main thread releases it.  And because the main thread initializes mT before unlocking, I have eliminated your race condition.

Comment: Any idea what was wrong with the locking based on the condition variable?

Comment: @harryjohston nope, I don't know `std::condition_variable`'s quirks well enough to debug it visually.  So I wrote a simpler version I could understand visually.

Answer (score 2):

0xcccccccc means "variable not initialized".  You have a threading race bug in your code.  The thread starts running before the "mT" variable is assigned.  You will need additional synchronization to block the thread until the assignment is completed so you can safely use mT.  This will then also ensure that the new thread can *see* the updated value of mT, a memory barrier is required on a multi-core machine.

Comment: Something strange is definitely going on. I tried to implement a lock and revised my post, but I am still getting the same situation. Is there something I am missing about the windows threading model?

Comment: mT is not assigned until the thread constructor returns. Your lockMe() function is presumably being called before that happens.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, Yes, but I don't think that is a problem. Especially in the second revision of the code. Now `con->wait(lock);//waits for host thread`, so if I remove `con->notify_one();` it will never reach the crash point. In my mind, I have a condition variable that is only released after the constructor has finished.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example code with `condition_variable` *and* `mutex`.

```
class threadContainer
{
    std::thread* mT;
    std::mutex m;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    bool flag;
    void lockMe() {
        // 1. you must acquire lock of mutex.
        unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
        // 2. and wait on `cv` for `flag==true`
        cv.wait(lk, [&]{ return flag; });
        cout << mT << endl;
        auto h = mT->native_handle();
    }
public:
    void run()
    {
        flag = false;
        mT = new std::thread( [&](){ this->lockMe(); } );
        {
            // 3. set `flag` and signal `cv`
            lock_guard<decltype(m)> lk(m);
            cout << mT << endl;
            flag = true;
            cv.notify_one();
        }
        mT->join();
    }
};
```

If what you really want to do is "initialize all threads with the highest priority state", how about this simplified code?
Anyway, changing thread priority is platform dependent and out of C++ Standard library.

```
class threadContainer
{
    std::thread thd;
    void work() {
        // (1) change thread priority itself
        ::SetThreadPriority(::GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST);
        // do something...
    }
public:
    void run()
    {
        thd = std::thread( [&](){ this->work(); } );
        // (2) or change thread priority from outside
        ::SetThreadPriority(thd.native_handle(), THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST);
        thd.join();
    }
};
```